# Convert data frame to mldr object to use in BR algorithm

Tags: multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am using BR algorithm for multi label prediction. I need to convert the test data to MLDR object. But I fail to do so, because test data does not have outcome column. 
I use mldr_from_dataframe(dataframe, labelIndices, attributes, name) for the conversion. In this "labelIndices" is a mandatory entry. So It does not work on my test data which does not have outcome columns(label indices). How can I make the conversion? So that I can use the test data to make the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

I could find that it's not required to convert test data to mldr format using mldr_from_dataframe. Just having dummy Binary variables for all the factor levels is good enough.